# How to Count decimal points using for loop?

Tags: c++

It's my first time to deal with Decimal points in C++ and i was wondering if i want the for loop to increase 0.01 by 0.01 instead of 1.0 by 1.0 what can i do.
I tried this but obviously it didn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 int main(){
    double i;
    for (i=1.5;i<1.68;i++);
      cout<<i;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
 }
```

How can i get this done?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Be careful with that: floating-point arithmetic is **imprecise**.

Comment: zneak is right, I'd recommend to multiply your boundaries by 100 if you need 2 numbers after decimal point.

Comment: For increments by 0.1, you have 1.5 then ~1.6 (it's imprecise) then ~1.7, which will certainly fail the < 1.68 test despite imprecision: each of the .1 additions can only be imprecise at around the 15th-17th significant digit for [`double`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), so two operations can't accumulate an error approaching 0.02 in magnitude.  Say incrementing by 0.01 though - you sure you didn't want to do that given the 1.68 value? - then you *would* have a serious issue - the easiest fix being to test for `< 1.685`, as error known < 0.005.

Comment: An issue with that approach is that anyone looking at the code may wonder at the extra digit, and whether it implies you intended a smaller increment (just as 1.68 suggesting 0.01 increments prompted my query above).  You can separate the increment amount into a different variable, then have `i < 1.68 + increment/2`, but it's still fragile - what if the increment was 0.1 and the original value was 1.65 - you increment it up to 1.7 then the imprecision does matter.  So, it's important to make sure you're testing against a value that's a multiple of increment beyond starting value, or use int...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int i;
  for (i=150;i<168;i+=10)
  {
    double d=i/100.0;
    cout<<d;
  }
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

One of mistakes in your code `for (i=1.5;i<1.68;i++);` is ";" after ")". It means, that this loop does nothing. I.e. next line `cout<<i;` is not inside body of loop.

Comment: The website tells me i need more five minutes before i can do that

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i = 1.5;i < 1.68;i = i + 0.1)
     cout << i << endl;
```

there will be no `;` after `for loop` otherwise it will become a `statement` and not work correctly..

`floating points` nature is unexpected so it sometimes becomes headache because of precision loss..so try to avoid them using in loop..always try to use `integer` in a `loop`..

so here is another answer and it is better than above and is less prone to any unexpected results

```
int i;
for (i = 150;i < 168;i += 10) {
     cout << i / 100.0 << endl;
}
```